# How can I listen to non reactive changes in my component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

So I have a very complex structure but I think I'm very clear on the issue and thus I'm mentioning the minimum requirement for the issue.

Consider following is a component that I've used.

```js
const SalesOrderLineItems = ({
  ...requiredProps,
}) => {
  const [productLines, setProductLines] = useState([])
  const [shippingLines, setShippingLines] = useState([])
  const [totals, setTotals] = useState({})
  const [discounts, setDiscounts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    // My main concern is this. I'd expect this to be triggered whenever I use setState in child component.
    console.log(' ~ productLines:', productLines)
  }, [productLines])

  const updateProductLines = useCallback((lines) => setProductLines(lines), [])
  const updateShippingLines = useCallback((lines) => setShippingLines(lines), [])
  return (
    <div className="SalesOrderLineItems">
      <SalesOrderProductLines
        updateProductLines={updateProductLines} 
        {...otherProps} />
      <SalesOrderShippingLines
        updateShippingLines={updateShippingLines}
        productLines={productLines} // Mainly for calculative purposes, Never used in rendering
        {...otherProps}
      />
      <SalesOrderDiscounts
        discounts={discounts}
        {...otherProps}
      />
      <SalesOrderTotals
        totals={totals}
        {...otherProps}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
export default SalesOrderLineItems
```

Now in `SalesOrderProductLines` component, I've used React Hook Form's watch which updates the productLines via passed prop like below.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = watch((value, { name, type }) => {
      // some business logic
      updateProductLines(value.lines)
      console.log(' ~ lines updated:', value.lines) // This gets logged with the latest values, So I'm assured that the above state update works fine!
    })
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe()
  }, [watch])
```

I think that my code uses uncontrolled inputs so it doesn't trigger any re-rendering thus preventing parent component to trigger the effect for productLines!

Do someone know how I can utilize something to find a way to listen to productLines change without triggering re-rendering for the performance changes? As I'm just going to set `totals` by performing calculations on the latest `productLines, shippingLines and discounts`.

Codesandbox can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-resonance-5bq3lq?file=/src/components/SalesOrderProductLines.jsx:1056-1128)

[image: Parent state doesn't trigger effect as per seen here]

Comment: Can you create a code sandbox ?

Comment: Sure, Let me try!

Comment: @ManishKumar added code sandbox!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62943406/19077766) looks like the problem is in useState. I totally recommend you to check that answer, but anyways, that work:

```
// SalesOrderProductLines.jsx
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = watch((value, { name, type }) => {
      // ...some business logic
      console.log("Parent component will not log this changes", value.lines);
      // you have to imitate previous state mutation or smth like this:)
      updateProductLines((p) => [...value.lines]);
    });
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [watch, updateProductLines]);
```

Comment: and btw, I'm not sure you need `const updateProductLines = useCallback((lines) => setProductLines(lines), [])`, as for me, you can send in props `setProductLines` because `watch(...)` is an useCallback with observer so I don't think you'll have an infinite rerender or anything else. I put `setProductLines` strict to props and it worked fine

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Ipa Stor.
It's working as expected now. Will reward your bounty in 21 hour!